# Is it possible to create a prepared statement for querying Oracle db with a hibernate session object instead of connection?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have a session object as shown below
Session session = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
Would it be possible to to create prepared statement with that for a query
in Java instead of the normal method using connection?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

org.hibernate Interface Session does not allow to work directly with JDBC, that means use prepared statements and so on.

org.hibernate Interface Session allows to work with Criteria API, HQL and Native queries.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html

But the doWork method of the org.hibernate Interface Session gives access to the Connection object managed by this Session and there you can make usual JDBC stuff - prepared statements and so on.

Examples are here:

https://www.javatips.net/api/org.hibernate.jdbc.work